# Clear oracle cache between queries

Tags: oracle10g

I want to get to know the real time of my query execution with different hints and without it. But oracle DB caches the query after its first execution and second time it executes quickly. How can I clear this cache after each query execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER SYSTEM FLUSH BUFFER_CACHE
```

More details in the manual:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_2013.htm#i2053602

Comment: To be accurate, this clears the cache of data blocks; it doesn't clear the cache of the query itself.

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp: a query cache was only introduced in 11g, before that there was no dedicated query cache. And in 11g Release **1** the query cache had to be enabled by hints in the statement.

Comment: Good point, but I wasn't referring to the query results cache, I was talking about the cursor cache.